# Return Nested XMLSCHEMA from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, xsd, nested

Is it possible to return a nested XMLSCHEMA from SQL Server 2005?

Right now I have a stored procedure to generate a NESTED select query that can be executed to return an XML document. I do this by appending this to the end of each nested query:

```
FOR XML AUTO   ,TYPE  ,ELEMENTS
```

I had though by just changing this to:

```
FOR XML AUTO   ,TYPE  ,ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA
```

that I might be able to return a nested XSD document.

What gets returned looks like an XSD with another entire XSD pasted inside, meaning each one had its own namespaces and schemaLocation. I just need them to appear as xsd:elements inside the root XSD.

```
SELECT 
   Stuff,
   (SELECT OtherStuff 
    FROM test2  
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA) 
FROM test 
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA
```

This is what is returned:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:schema="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet26" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet26" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="test" type="sqltypes:xml" />
</xsd:schema>
<test xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet26">
  <Stuff>Stuff</Stuff>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:schema="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet25" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" xmlns="" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet25" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="test2">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="OtherStuff" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:simpleType>
              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <test2 xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet25">
    <OtherStuff>OtherStuff</OtherStuff>
  </test2>
</test>
```

This is what I need to be returned:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:schema="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet26" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sql:SqlRowSet26" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="test" type="sqltypes:xml" />
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Stuff" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="test2">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="OtherStuff" minOccurs="0">
                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                                    <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                                </xsd:restriction>
                            </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

What SQL is returning is actually syntactically incorrect XML. There should not be two ROOT elements

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to that or you rolled your own manually?

Comment: I ended up writing a custom java project to manipulate the xml returned.